# How can I capture the page URL with an embedded Typeform (using hidden fields)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, typeform

I'm hoping to embed a Typeform onto different articles in my documentation centre. However, I need to capture the page URl using hidden fields, so I can link which feedback was left on what article page.

Currently, the responses are aggregated and I don't know which article the user left feedback on.
Here's what the embed code looks like (I've also added a hidden field titled `article_url`):

> `<div data-tf-widget="a1B2c3D4" data-tf-opacity="0" data-tf-hide-headers data-tf-hide-footer data-tf-hidden="article_url=xxxxx" style="width:100%;height:350px;"></div><script src="//embed.typeform.com/next/embed.js"></script>`

I'm sure I can do this with hidden fields and maybe a `window.location.href` function within the embed code & using jquery, but I'm not sure how the script would look and my coding skills are a bit rusty.

Answer (score 7):

You can update your typeform embed code directly with JavaScript like this:

```js
const formElement = document.querySelector('[data-tf-widget=a1B2c3D4]')
formElement.dataset.tfHidden = `article_url=${window.location.href}`
```

However since you are already using custom JavaScript you can use Typeform Embed Library ([see on Github](https://github.com/Typeform/embed/tree/main/packages/embed)) for more control over your embedded forms:

```html
<div id="form" style="width: 100%; height: 350px"></div>
<script src="//embed.typeform.com/next/embed.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//embed.typeform.com/next/css/widget.css" />
<script>
  const formId = 'a1B2c3D4'
  const container = document.querySelector('#form')
  window.tf.createWidget(formId, {
    container,
    hideHeaders: true,
    hideFooter: true,
    opacity: 0,
    hidden: {
      article_url: window.location.href,
    },
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Having a bit of trouble still. We use Zendesk guide so our scripts and HTML are in different sheets: script.js & article_page.hbs.

script.js:
`const formId = 'a1B2c3D4'
  const container = document.querySelector('#typeform-form')
  window.tf.createWidget(formId, {
    container,
    hideHeaders: true,
    hideFooter: true,
    opacity: 0,
    hidden: {
      article_url: window.location.href,
    },
  })`

article_page.hbs
        `<div id="typeform-form" data-tf-widget="a1B2c3D4" style="width:100%;height:350px;color:#FFFFFF;"></div><script src="//embed..js"></script>`

Comment: You are mixing the 2 approaches I listed in my answer. If you want the script to live in a separate JS file you need to **use the second approach**. 
 
Your HTML (HBS) file should contain just the div with id attribute and script: `<div id="form" style="width: 100%; height: 350px"></div><script src="//embed.typeform.com/next/embed.js"></script>`
 
The content of the `<script>` can be extracted into a separate JS file (eg. `script.js`).

Comment: Hi there - implemented what you mentioned and still having some trouble. Here's a screenshot of my script (script.js) and article page (article_page.hbs): https://share.getcloudapp.com/kpunnpoE. Any insight would help! The article_url field in typeform is still showing up blank.

Comment: @TasK you need to remove all `data-tf-` attributes from the DIV and keep only the JS code. Like this working example: https://antique-sugar-pirate.glitch.me/

Comment: If someone else is having trouble, make sure to also add the desired hidden field(s) within the typeform management page, and then publish the changes!